# Adding static routes

Tags: networking, centos, routing

I'm kind of new in networks and I have to add static routes to few networks on CentOS. Here are 2 questions that I have:

1. How to add this: `10.10.x.x/16` is this valid entry and is this mean all IP's on `x.x` will be valid?
2. If I'm understand correctly I need to create file with the name of the interface via which will be routing in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`. Is that correct?

Comment: 1) You want `10.10.0.0/16`. 2) The file should be `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-$INTERFACE`.

Comment: So the correct way isn't `10.10.x.x/16` but `10.10.0.0/16`?

Comment: @jordanm is correct.  `10.10.0.0/16` is the **preferred** way.  That said, you can have any two numbers in the last two places (they will just be ignored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jordanm said you need to add this in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-INTERFACENAME`

Add following lines

```
10.10.0.0/16 via IP dev INTERFACENAME
```

Change **IP** and **INTERFACENAME** with yours. After this restart your network

```
service network restart
```

More information [Configuring Static Routes](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html)